# write variable from inside shader for outside use

Tags: glsl, three.js, webgl, shader

From inside the shader I can't modify uniforms or attributes. Is there a way I could write a variable that I can use outside the shader?

My goal is to determine the lowest and the highest vertex on the z-axis. I could of course run through all the vertices in a for loop, but the shader runs through them anyway and is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The shader's output, always, is pixels. Anything other than that would violate the stream-processing nature of the GPU. You could read the result pixel values...